# Uploading multiple images using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

So i am trying to create a jquery and php upload, but not to only upload multiple but also added text field and multiple select. how ever the code work normally but i want to use jquery to submit the form to the php file that would move the upload to the dir and submit information to the database.

**HTML**

```
<input multiple type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" id="file[]" class="file-styled file" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg">
```

**Jquery**

```
function serealizeSelects (select)
        {
            var array = [];
            select.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
            return array;
        }
        var tagz = serealizeSelects($(".tagz option"));
        var files = $('#file[]').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var category = $('#category').val();

        $.post('upload.php', {tagz:tagz, title:title, category:category      }, function(data){

            $('#confirm').html(data);

        });
```

My question is How can i get the value of the file field to submit to the php file

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use dropzone.js library ..its so.easy to setup and has a powerful documentation .

Comment: Please note questions or answers [that] *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*